# NDK compilation difference between linux and windows

Tags: android, linux, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I'm wondering if someone has experienced issue like me. I have two laptops in one of them has **Ubuntu Linux14.04** the other one **Windows** OS. On Ubuntu there is **android-ndk-r9c** and on Windows **android-ndk-r9d**. ndk-build has being **successful** on both of them. However the windows compiled version works on android, on Linux compiled there is crash from **native** side. Is there any **difference** between Windows and Ubuntu NDKs? What can be the cause of the crash on android which uses the version of .so libs which compiled on Ubuntu Linux? 
Thanks in advance..

Comment: I don't think, that it's windows' or linux' fault as the ndk comes with its own toolchains. Probably you've encountered a bug in the abi/the compiler that got fixed with version [9d](https://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html#).

Comment: I also tried with android ndk r10d, still problems are remaining http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27596716/android-ndk-r10d-error