# Android NDK r10d error

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I'm trying to compile some media library which uses some part of ffmpeg. I'm having following errors:

```
/home/pro/android-ndk-r10d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/linux-x86/lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.8/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: error: conditional branch to PLT in THUMB-2 not supported yet. libavcodec/arm/videodsp_armv5te.S:29: error: unexpected opcode while processing relocation R_ARM_THM_JUMP19 clang++: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Application.mk file

```
APP_STL := gnustl_shared
APP_PLATFORM := android-9
APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a
NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION=clang
```

On NDK r9c I did not experienced that kind of errors. Any help, suggestions...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6602929/which-compiler-does-android-ndk-use note final answ. On gcc version in tool chain export to revert 4.8 to earlier .

Comment: In my case after switching to `4.9` this problem gone

Comment: Yeah, also in later ndk toolchain versions there is not that kind of problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, so I just had the same problem.

You need to use this Android NDK : **Revision 10e (May 2015)**

You can download from here : https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads/older_releases.html

which works for me.